# What projection does the global climate region map from Wikipedia use?

Tags: coordinate-system

I would like to use this [global climate region map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ClimateMap_World.png) from Wikipedia as a "basemap" (by plotting over the image in R).

[image]

Is it possible to determine the projection of this map?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I concur with **steko** that it appears to be a [Robinson projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_projection). I can't claim to have definitive proof, but I did overlay the [example Robinson projection image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Robinson_projection_SW.jpg) from Wikipedia with the provided climate region map and, to my eyes, the alignment of features appears exact.

Here is an animated GIF to illustrate:

[image: Animated GIF comparing Robinson projection with unknown map projection]

(You may have to reload the page or image to get the animation to repeat.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say [EcKert III](http://www.mapthematics.com/ProjectionsList.php?Projection=50#Eckert%20III), [Eckert IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckert_IV_projection) or [Winkel II](http://www.mapthematics.com/ProjectionsList.php?Projection=103#Winkel%20II).